# Can I create interface for enums in C#

Tags: c#, enums

Suppose I have two enums as follow:

```
namespace A
{
    public enum AE
    {
        AE_0,
        AE_1
    }
}

namespace B
{
    public enum BE
    {
        BE_0,
        BE_1
    }
}
```

I would like to use these two enums looks like one so that, in a function, we can use both F(AE) and F(BE) without defining two functions.

As far as I know, we can create an interface for two different classes so that if we assign the interface as a parameter, these two classes can be used.

Can I do the same for enum?

Thank you.

**Edit**: I raise the problem because I already have enum A in namespace A. Now I would like to add enum B in namespace B without touching anything in namespace A. However, in namespace A, I already have a function F with enum A as parameter. Now I would like to use function F with enum B in namespace B. I got an error because enum A and enum B cannot convert to each other. Thank you.

Comment: You either want to create a function that takes a generic, or just take advantage of the fact that enums are just `int`s by default. Either way, an interface seems unnecessary here.

Comment: Agree with Lynn, using generics, might just work here, and add a `where T : struct` constraint. For example: `void F<T>(T input) where T : struct { ... }`

Comment: If the enums are interchangable, should they really be distinct enums?

Comment: so you want to invoke either `F(AE.AE_1)` or `F(BE.BE_1)` ? If yes, could you share your scenario? There might be a better solution

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot, because an `enum` inherits from [`System.Enum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum(v=vs.110).aspx) and nothing more.

Additionally, despite obvious appearances, applying an interface to an enum would *not* yield the desired results, since the enum members are implemented as `static` values, and an `interface` cannot specify `static` values.

Finally, if you have something that really should accept two kinds of `enum` parameters, consider whether they should be two separate `enum`s, or a single `enum` with [[Flags]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: `enum` doesn't inherit from `System.Enum`, an `enum` *is* a `System.Enum`

Comment: @DavidG Not according to ILDasm. `enum MyEnum` becomes `.class private auto ansi sealed MyEnum
       extends [mscorlib]System.Enum`

Comment: @DavidG, he sad "an enum inherits...", not "Enum inherits..."  Emphasis on the "an."

Answer (score 3):

Like others have mentioned, it might be best to use a generic method since C# doesn't let you create an interface for an enum. I've created a quick sample that let's you pass in members from different enumerations.

```
namespace A
{
    public enum AE
    {
        AE_0,
        AE_1
    }

    public class DoSomething
    {
        public static void F<T>(T enumMember) where T : struct
        {
            // exit early if something other than enum entered
            if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("T is not enum");
            }

            // Do whatever you need to do here
            Console.WriteLine(enumMember.ToString());
        }
    }
}

namespace B
{
    public enum BE
    {
        BE_0,
        BE_1
    }
}

namespace C
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void processEnum()
        {
            A.DoSomething.F<A.AE>(A.AE.AE_0);
            A.DoSomething.F<B.BE>(B.BE.BE_0);
        }
    }
}
```