# Accept more than one type of enum in functions

Tags: c#, enums, uwp

I currently have two enums :

```cs
public enum LigneComponent
{
    LIEN = 0,
    SUPPORT = 1,
    OUVRAGE = 2,
}



public enum PosteComponent
{
    BT = 0,
    COMPTEUR = 1,
    AMM = 2,
    TFM = 3,
    HTA = 4,
    DLD = 5,
    GENERALITES = 6
}
```

and I'm using one of the enum in another class :

```cs
public class ExcelReader
{
    internal Dictionary<InfosPosteViewModel.PosteComponent, StorageFile> ExcelDataFiles { get; set; }

    internal async Task SetupExcelFiles(Dictionary<InfosPosteViewModel.PosteComponent, string> fileKeyNames, StorageFolder filesDirectory)
    {
        //code sample here
    }
}
```

but now I want to make that `Dictionary` and that function more generic to make it accept the two different types of enum but I still don't want it to accept more than these two types, is there a way to do that easily ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I create interface for enums in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405774/can-i-create-interface-for-enums-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Because the 2 enums share the same underlying values, you should create 2 separate dictionaries, 1 for PosteComponent and 1 for LigneComponent.  Other strategies for combining can't differentiate between values such as LIEN vs BT

Comment: ok, that are some bad news

Comment: Would it make sense to replace those two enums with just one?

Comment: Not really in that case, I'm using these enums in two different classes and they're focusing on two different parts of my application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# 7.3 includes an `Enum` contraint that you can use to enforce the type to be *any* enumeration type:

```
public class ExcelReader<T> where T : Enum
{
    internal Dictionary<T, StorageFile> ExcelDataFiles { get; set; }

    internal async Task SetupExcelFiles(Dictionary<T, string> fileKeyNames, StorageFolder filesDirectory)
    {
        //code sample here
    }
}
```

There is no support in the language for specifying specific types of enums though, at least not at compile time. You can always check the type at runtime:

```
internal async Task SetupExcelFiles(Dictionary<T, string> fileKeyNames, StorageFolder filesDirectory)
{
    if (typeof(T) != typeof(LigneComponent) && typeof(T) != typeof(PosteComponent))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid type argument");

    //code sample here
}
```

Comment: Your solution is a very nice workaround and it works well for what I want to do, thanks a lot !